# How to import data from tsv file in postgreSQL procedure?

Tags: sql, postgresql, procedure, error-messaging

I have a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE import(IN tablename varchar, IN path text, IN separator char) AS $$
    BEGIN
            EXECUTE format('COPY %s FROM ''%s'' DELIMITER ''%s'' CSV HEADER;', tablename, path, separator);
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I call like this:
`CALL import('transactions', '/home/vladimir/Desktop/RetailAnalitycs_v1.0/datasets/Transactions.tsv','\t');`

this option works on macOS but doesn't work on linux, what could be the reason?
produces the following error: `[58P01] ERROR: could not open file "/home/vladimir/Desktop/RetailAnalitycs_v1.0/datasets/Transactions.tsv" for reading: No such file or directory Подсказка: COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.`

But I am 100% sure that the path to the file is correct.

I tried to use a different separator, rewrote the procedure, asked chatgpt.

Comment: the postgres program can not have access rights to the file as they belong usually only to the user

Comment: Where is the Postgres server located, on the same machine as `/home/vladimir/ ...` or another machine?

Comment: @Adrian Klaver
The server is located on the same local computer where the files. The only thing I note is that the Postgres server is running through a docker container.

Comment: @ndk What can I try to do? I literally tried everything that was recommended to me on the Internet.

Comment: `COPY` works as the server user and from it's view point. Obviously the server cannot reach outside the Docker container to get to the `"/home/vladimir/Desktop ...` path. You will need to move the file to a path the server can reach.

Comment: @Adria Klaver I ran PostgreSQL on pc. Now the error is: Access denied. 
Terminal command: 
postgres=# \COPY transactions
FROM '/home/vladimir/Desktop/RetailAnalitycs_v1.0/datasets/Transactions.tsv'
DELIMITER E'\t'
TSV HEADER;
Tried chmod but it didn't help.

Comment: You need the information in the comment as update to your question. Also add more information 1) More complete description of what '...  ran PostgreSQL on pc.` means? 2) What is throwing the error; 'Now the error is: Access denied' 3) Tried `chmod` on what?